# Filter formula bringing in some data, but omitting or erroring out on last two columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a worksheet with three tables. Yellow = product id, product, agent name. Green = product ID, Status, Comment, Date. Blue = product id, status, start date, end date.

I have two drop downs in cell a21 = agent name // cell b21 = status

Below that I have headers = ID  Product Status  Days in Status  Comment Date
and then I have a calc in cell a23 to bring in the filtered data based on those three tables.

```
=LET( 
  statusIds, FILTER(J2:J19, K2:K19 = B21), 
  table1_, LAMBDA(col, FILTER(col, C2:C19 = A21, MATCH(A2:A19, statusIds, 0))), 
  agentIds, table1_(A2:A19), 
  products, table1_(B2:B19), 
  table2_, LAMBDA(col, FILTER(col, K2:K19 = B21, MATCH(J2:J19, agentIds, 0))), 
  statuses, table2_(K2:K19), 
  durations, table2_(ARRAYFORMULA(M2:M19 - L2:L19)), 
  allComments, MAP(agentIds, LAMBDA(id, IFERROR(FILTER(G2:G19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = 
INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), ""))),
  allDates, MAP(agentIds, LAMBDA(id, IFERROR(FILTER(H2:H19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = 
INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), ""))),
  sortedAllDates, ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(FLATTEN(allDates), 1, FALSE)),
  sortedComments, MAP(allComments, LAMBDA(comments, IFERROR(comments, ""))),
  IFNA(HSTACK(agentIds, products, statuses, durations, sortedComments, sortedAllDates))
)
```

in this google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13o5d1AhslmYP3BcO1U16DxkyoCxo44rt7wgOKcq-PeE/edit#gid=532197745

you can see that it brings in the both rows fine until the comments and date columns. Any ideas why?

Comment: It looks like you included code from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, [edit] to make sure you do **ALL** the following: 1.Include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, 2. Mention the author's name, and 3. [Quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SUGGESTION

I made some changes to your provided script:

```
=LET( 
  statusIds, FILTER(J2:J19, K2:K19 = B21), 
  table1_, LAMBDA(col, FILTER(col, C2:C19 = A21, MATCH(A2:A19, statusIds, 0))), 
  agentIds, table1_(A2:A19), 
  products, table1_(B2:B19), 
  table2_, LAMBDA(col, FILTER(col, K2:K19 = B21, MATCH(J2:J19, agentIds, 0))), 
  statuses, table2_(K2:K19), 
  durations, table2_(ARRAYFORMULA(M2:M19 - L2:L19)), 
  allComments, MAP(agentIds, LAMBDA(id, INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER(G2:G19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), ""),
  COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(G2:G19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), ""))))),
  allDates, MAP(agentIds, LAMBDA(id, MAX(IFERROR(FILTER(H2:H19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), "")))),
  IFNA(HSTACK(agentIds, products, statuses, durations, allComments, allDates))
)
```

Among the changes I did are removing the `sortedComments` and `sortedAllDAtes` definitions, and instead integrated their functions to the `allComments` and `allDates` definitions, respectively.

- **allComments changes**

From:

```
MAP(agentIds, LAMBDA(id, IFERROR(FILTER(G2:G19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = 
INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), "")))
```

To:

```
MAP(agentIds, LAMBDA(id, INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER(G2:G19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), ""),
COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(G2:G19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), "")))))
```

What happens here is that I've integrated the filtering of the most recent comment made for the specific ID and status to the map, thus only returning one cell of comment per ID. This was done by running the filter through an indexing, in order to get the most recent comment (i.e. the last entry on the array)

This is a problem I've noticed when there are IDs that has multiple comments referenced to it; because you are only returning one row of data per ID but are returning multiple rows of comments from the map, the topmost row of data will have issues returning the array because there is subsequent data displayed from the next ID. (see screenshots below)

[image]

If there is only one ID with multiple comments, it would be able to display them normally.

[image]

However, for entries with multiple IDs, the issue appears since from the previous mapping, there are 2 comments referenced for ID 1011 but there is existing data for ID 5001 that cannot be overlapped.

- **allDates changes**

From:

```
MAP(agentIds, LAMBDA(id, IFERROR(FILTER(H2:H19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = 
INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), "")))
```

To:

```
MAP(agentIds, LAMBDA(id, MAX(IFERROR(FILTER(H2:H19, (E2:E19 = id) * (F2:F19 = INDEX(statuses, MATCH(id, agentIds, 0)))), ""))))
```

A similar approach was made to get the most recent date for multiple comment entries, wherein I used the [MAX function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013) to get the most recent date from the filtered dates.

### OUTPUT

[image]

Note: I also noticed some misspellings of "negotiating" on the sheet, which may cause some error values when running the function.

Comment: Hey can you make a sheet in the workbook link that I shared in my post to include what you have in that video? I tried using your formula you updated, but still getting an error on the second row of data being brought in

Comment: Hi @NidenK I've made a copy of your main sheet in the workbook that has the formula working; I've also highlighted that section of the sheet that has a misspelling of "negotiating", which causes the formula to not pick up.